# Proving L'Hospital's rule

Tags: limits, derivatives

I was trying to prove  L'Hospital's rule when  $L= \displaystyle \lim\limits_{x \to a}\dfrac {f(x)}{g(x)}$=$\dfrac {\infty} 
{\infty}$.

So this is what I currently tried to prove that this $L= \displaystyle \lim\limits_{x \to a} \dfrac {f(x)}{g(x)}$ is equal to $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}\dfrac {f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ .

This is what I have tried, $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} \dfrac {1/g(x)}{1/f(x)}=\frac {0}{0}$.

Now I know this can be proved by the baby version, but I would like to see if I can do it without that.

So when we know that $\dfrac{1}{g(a)}=0$ and $\dfrac{1}{f(a)}=0$. So ${}=\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x \to a}\dfrac {1/g(x)-1/g(a)}{1/f(x)-1/f(a)}$.

I just do not know what to do after this, I tried taking the LCM of $g(x)$ and $g(a)$ but I could not get anywhere. If anyone   could help me proving this without using the baby method and rather use the meaning of a differential which is what proves the baby method, $${}= \displaystyle \lim\limits_{x \to a} \dfrac {\frac {f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}}{\frac {g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}}=\dfrac {f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#Proof_of_L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

For any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $a_\varepsilon>0$ such that
$\Big|\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}-L\Big|<\varepsilon$ whenever $a<x\leq a_\varepsilon$.

For any $a<x<y<a_\varepsilon$, an application of the mean value theorem gives

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{g(y)-g(x)}&=\frac{f'(c_{x,y})}{g'(c_{x,y})}
\end{align}
$$
for some $x<c_{x,y}< y$. From
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{g(y)-g(x)}&=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\frac{1-\frac{f(y)}{f(x)}}{1-\frac{g(y)}{g(x)}}
\end{align}
$$
we obtain
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= \frac{f'(c_{x,y})}{g'(c_{x,y})}\frac{1-\frac{g(y)}{g(x)}}{1-\frac{f(y)}{f(x)}}
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}&= \Big(\frac{f'(c_{x,y})}{g'(c_{x,y})} -L +L\Big)\left(\frac{1-\frac{g(y)}{g(x)}}{1-\frac{f(y)}{f(x)}}-1+1\right)\\
&=\Big(\frac{f'(c_{x,y})}{g'(c_{x,y})} -L\Big)\left(\frac{1-\frac{g(y)}{g(x)}}{1-\frac{f(y)}{f(x)}}-1\right) + L\left(\frac{1-\frac{g(y)}{g(x)}}{1-\frac{f(y)}{f(x)}}-1\right) + \\& \quad\quad \Big(\frac{f'(c_{x,y})}{g'(c_{x,y})} -L\Big) + L
\end{align}
$$

and so

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} - L&= \Big(\frac{f'(c_{x,y})}{g'(c_{x,y})} -L +L\Big)\left(\frac{1-\frac{g(y)}{g(x)}}{1-\frac{f(y)}{f(x)}}-1+1\right) - L\\
&=\Big(\frac{f'(c_{x,y})}{g'(c_{x,y})} -L\Big)\left(\frac{1-\frac{g(y)}{g(x)}}{1-\frac{f(y)}{f(x)}}-1\right) + L\left(\frac{1-\frac{g(y)}{g(x)}}{1-\frac{f(y)}{f(x)}}-1\right) + \Big(\frac{f'(c_{x,y})}{g'(c_{x,y})} -L\Big)
\end{align}
$$

The factor $\Big|\frac{f'(c_{x,y})}{g'(c_{x,y})} -L\Big|<\varepsilon$ since $a<x<c_{x,y}<y<a_\varepsilon$.  By letting  $x\rightarrow a$, we get
$$
\left(\frac{1-\frac{g(y)}{g(x)}}{1-\frac{f(y)}{f(x)}}-1\right)\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow a}0
$$
and so,
$$
\limsup_{x\rightarrow a}\Big|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-L\Big|\leq 2\varepsilon
$$
for all $\varepsilon>0$. This implies that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists and equals $L$.

---

If you are not comfortable with $\limsup$'s then you can try to further exploit $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=\infty=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)$ the show that the factor

$$
\left(\frac{1-\frac{g(y)}{g(x)}}{1-\frac{f(y)}{f(x)}}-1\right)
$$

is less than some small term depending on $\varepsilon$.